# Which IAM user am I in the console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a bit confused about AWS IAM. which user am I when I'm in the console? I am currently trying to make a s3 policy for one of my buckets. and I'm getting an error saying `Access denied` which I believe is due to not having the correct permissions for one user. so I gave this user fullS3 access. but I'm still getting `Access denied`.

so which user does the console think I am? if that makes sense? or how can I give that user controlling the console the correct s3 access?

Answer (score 1):

The user you are in the console is whichever user you logged in as. If you haven't created a user, and you're logging in to the console with your email address, then you're the root user, which has full permissions. There are still some reasons that you could be getting access denied though.

Is it possible you've already applied a bucket policy which denies access to all? If so, you could try deleting the current policy rather than changing it in the console, then applying the new one. Sometimes you will need to remove the policy with the CLI though.

If not, could it be this issue? [Access denied when put bucket policy on aws s3 bucket with root user (= bucket owner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373840/access-denied-when-put-bucket-policy-on-aws-s3-bucket-with-root-user-bucket-o)

If neither of these work, please confirm which user you are logged in as (it'll say in the top right hand corner), and the JSON for the policy you're trying to apply.